# nodeclipse debugger doesn't stop at all breakpoints

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I have node.js express application opened inside eclipse with nodeclipse plugin installed. The application run successfully and properly. But when I try to set some breakpoints, the debugger stops only at some of them. Is it incomplete feature in nodeclipse? or is there any other better way to benefit from eclipse debugging tool?

Answer (score 0):

Check news http://www.nodeclipse.org/ and get the latest Nodeclipse

if there problem is still there, raise issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/